# AWS - Prevent admin users from elevating their own permission

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have several users who are part of the admin group in AWS and have full access to all the resources. I don't want them to elevate their permissions and add themselves to a group whenever they get stuck somewhere.
Is there any way to have an IAM policy to prevent those users from granting themselves elevated permissions?

Thank you

Comment: You're trying to solve a people problem with a technology solution, and that never works. It is certainly possible to deny `iam:AddUserToGroup`, but that's only the start. You'd also have to prevent them from attaching any policies to their user, or assuming a role that either has elevated privileges or can grant them, or any of a dozen other ways to elevate your privileges. At which point you don't have "admin" users any more, and you've probably prevented them from doing their real work.

Comment: The real question should be why they need to add themselves to a group. Although to be honest, that seems like an excellent way for an _administrator_ to acquire temporary privileges (as long as they remove themselves afterwards). Assumed roles are a more traditional approach, but are harder to track via CloudTrail.

Comment: If they are part of an Admin group, don't they _already_ have full permissions? You can put them in a Power User group, which gives them everything except IAM permissions, so they can't give other users extra permissions.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein yes, they are part of the admin group so I want them to be able to add other users to the groups but want to have something implemented so they cannot add themselves to other groups that  they are not part of already.

Comment: @Parsifal, thank you, that is exactly what I was after. Need them to be able to add other users to the groups but not themselves. is there any way to have them assume admin rights (* on all resource) but have a condition that checks and if they are trying to escalate their own permission it stops them?

Comment: similar, this didn't work:
 `{           "Sid": "AllowAdminAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "iam:AddUserToGroup",
                "iam:AttachGroupPolicy",
                "iam:PutGroupPolicy"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:user/${aws:username}",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "aws:username": "test.user"`

Comment: Again, you're trying to solve a people problem with a technological solution. It won't work.